# Whats the correct way to alloc a UIImage to memory and release it iphone

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uiimageview

Using Instruments, I keep on getting pointed to a memory leak with a UIImage.
I think I'm assigning and releasing the memory correctly. The leaked object in instruments is described as NSConcreteData

Is the following the correct way to assign and release a UIImage?

```
UIImage* flagimg = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url2]];    
[flagimg release];
flagimg =nil;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[UIImage imageWithData:]` returns an autoreleased object, which should not be released by you again. So this code snipped contains not a memory leak but the opposite, a double free (in the worst case).

Note that Instruments sometimes generates false positives and/or reports memory leaks in the Foundation itself (yep, they make mistakes too :-).

The fastest way to alloc/release an object is to avoid convenience initializers (like imageWithData:) and instead to something like

> `NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url]];
>
> UIImage* img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
>
> [data release];
>
> // use your image
>
> [img release];`

This will allocate and release your object right away and not wait until the autorelease pool is cleaned.

But please note too, that a memory leak is generally not memory that is not *yet* freed, but that is lost and *cannot be freed anymore*, so an object which will be deallocated by the autorelease pool is not considered a memory leak.

Comment: Whats the consequence of a "double release" ?

Comment: Usually a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (commonly called segfault) which causes your program to crash. Those happen too if you have a reference to an object which is already deallocated and you try to access it.

Answer (score 1):

as a general rule you can say

if you create an object an theres a "init","copy" or "retain" in it, you have to release it.
if not, you get an autoreleased object.

thats not always true, but in most cases

Answer (score 0):

both `imageWithData` and `dataWithContentsOfURL` return autoreleased objects, so you should have no memory leaks in that code snippet.

Since `flagimg` is returned autoreleased, your `[flagimg release];` call is not needed; you're over-releasing that object.