# How do you manage memory when adding a UIImageView to another windows view?

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory, uiimageview, screen

Since I think I scared everyone away with my other recent post ( [Memory management when adding a UIImageView to another viewController's view from another viewController's view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225334/memory-management-when-adding-a-uiimageview-to-another-viewcontrollers-view-from) ) and I'm running out of time, I'd just like to ask this in simpler terms.  If you want to know I'm doing with more detail, refer to the other post.

How do you manage memory, and releasing, when adding a UIImageView to another windows view?

i.e. I'm creating a UIImageView in one view, and adding it as a subview in another windows view. The other window is being used by a TV.

Right now I have:

```
            mapImageViewEx = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

            // I think you can ignore these two things below
            CGPoint p = mapScrollView.contentOffset;
            mapImageViewEx.frame = CGRectMake((p.x*-1), (p.y*-1), mapImageView.frame.size.width, mapImageView.frame.size.height);

            NSString *mapExFileLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[map_List objectAtIndex:mapNum] ofType:@"png"];
            NSData *mapExIMGData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:mapExFileLocation];
            mapImageViewEx.image = [UIImage imageWithData:mapExIMGData];

            // finds the other window's view controller's view
            UIView *containerExViewP = (UIView*)[del.switchExVC.view viewWithTag:9000];

            // adds it
            [containerExViewP addSubview:mapImageViewEx];
```

Problem I'm having is that it keeps stacking up memory use every time I exit the view.  Releasing the image in the iPad screen view's dealloc does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
        mapImageViewEx = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
```

to

```
        mapImageViewEx = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
```

autorelease means that the reference count will be decremented at some unknown point in the future.

the addSubview will increment the count, so you don't have to worry about it.

As long as the parent view is properly disposed of, mapImageViewEx will be released.

Comment: Tried that. It crashes the 2nd time I go to the view where the picture goes to the TV. Any ideas?

Comment: you probably have a different problem then.  There aren't any other obvious memory leaks in the code you posted.

Comment: Leaks app does not detect a leak.

Comment: Sorry.  I should have said memory errors.  You have the opposite problem.  if it crashes, something is likely being over released.  Are you releasing mapImageViewEx anywhere else?

Comment: According to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507145/whats-the-correct-way-to-alloc-a-uiimage-to-memory-and-release-it-iphone imageWithData returns an autoreleased object. The answer provided shows both the NSData and UIImage being releases